# Почему не отображаеться сервис в списке сервисов

Tags: python, windows

Здравствйте, создаю бота и хочу что бы он роботал как служба Windows, Но когда запускаю в CMD через команду python namefile.py install/start, все роботает, но я не могу найти названия сервиса которое я прописал в файле в списке служб WIndows'а. Можете подсказать что делать. Вот код программы.

```
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager

import listTT


class AppServerSvc(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "Я ПРОСТО БОТ"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Я ПРОСТО БОТ"
    _svc_description_ = "Я ПРОСТО БОТ"
def __init__(self, args):
    win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
    self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
    self.hWaitResume = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
    self.timeout = 1000  # Пауза между выполнением основного цикла службы в миллисекундах
    self.resumeTimeout = 1000
    self._paused = False

def SvcStop(self):
    self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
    servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                          servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STOPPED,
                          (self._svc_name_, ''))
    win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

def SvcPause(self):
    self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING)
    self._paused = True
    self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_PAUSED)
    servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("The %s service has paused." % (self._svc_name_,))

def SvcContinue(self):
    self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING)
    win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitResume)
    self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)
    servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("The %s service has resumed." % (self._svc_name_,))

def SvcDoRun(self):
    self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)
    servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                          servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                          (self._svc_name_, ''))
    self.main()

    # В этом методе реализовываем нашу службу

def main(self):
    # Здесь выполняем необходимые действия при старте службы
    servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("RDIF bot is here!")

    while True:
        # Здесь должен находиться основной код сервиса

        # in TeleBot class added param loop_timeout (secs) for exit from loop and check service state.
        '''
        def polling(self, none_stop=False, interval=0, timeout=20, loop_timeout=0):
            if self.threaded:
                self.__threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout, loop_timeout)
            else:
                self.__non_threaded_polling(none_stop, interval, timeout, loop_timeout)
        .........
        def __threaded_polling(self, none_stop=False, interval=0, timeout=3, loop_timeout=0):
            .........
            time_out = time.time() + loop_timeout
            while not self.__stop_polling.wait(interval):
                if time.time() > time_out and loop_timeout != 0: break
                .........
        def __non_threaded_polling(self, none_stop=False, interval=0, timeout=3, loop_timeout=0):
            .........
            time_out = time.time() + loop_timeout
            while not self.__stop_polling.wait(interval):
                if time.time() > time_out and loop_timeout != 0: break
                    .........
        '''
        listTT.bot.polling(none_stop=True, loop_timeout=30)

        # Проверяем не поступила ли команда завершения работы службы
        rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitStop, self.timeout)
        if rc == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            # Здесь выполняем необходимые действия при остановке службы
            servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("Bye!")
            break

        # Здесь выполняем необходимые действия при приостановке службы
        if self._paused:
            servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("I'm paused... Keep waiting...")
        # Приостановка работы службы
        while self._paused:
            # Проверям не поступила ли команда возобновления работы службы
            rc = win32event.WaitForSingleObject(self.hWaitResume, self.resumeTimeout)
            if rc == win32event.WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                self._paused = False
                # Здесь выполняем необходимые действия при возобновлении работы службы
                servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("Yeah! Let's continue!")
                break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

- Можете подсказать что нужно добавить что сервис сам себе перезапускал, когда вылазят ошибки в боте

Comment: Вопрос конечно сам по себе интересный, но вообще для работы бота не требуется, чтобы он был сервисом, достаточно чтобы он работал как обычное приложение без окон.

Comment: @ insolor   Но как тогда сделать что бы он роботал как приложения, если не через сервис ?

Comment: Можно просто сделать обычный скрипт, запускать через pythonw - будет запускаться в фоновом режиме без окон.

Comment: @insolor Хорошо идея, но мне просто интересно, как тогда сделать чтобы он сама перезапускался если выскочит ошибка в боте?

Comment: @insolor И кстате я пробовал сделать через pyw, но он просто не хочет роботать нормально. То-есть он запускаеться, но сам бот не отвечает на команды и на все остольное

Comment: Как вариант можно через try - except ловить все ошибки. Если у вас не работает через pyw, то нужно разбираться почему.

Comment: @insolor спасибо большое что подсказали

Answer (score 1):

Создал сервис  через команду `sc create JUSTBOT2 binpath="path1(exe) path2(py)" DisplayName="JUSTBOT2" start=auto` И запустил через список служб и все роботает. А что бы оно перезапускалось в настройках поставил Restart the program